# How to delete extra Compute Engine and App Engine Client ID at Google developers console Credentials section

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-compute-engine

I discovered 28 OAuth Client ID items marked "Compute Engine and App Engine" at the "APIs & AUTH - Credentials" section of Google developers console. I suppose that them were created automatically, when I tried to activate Google Compute Engine API using account without "owner" permissions. I tried API activation few times from different browsers earlier, as I thought that the reason of failure is some script error, but not the account permissions.

Now I can not add new Client ID for the service account to work with Google Compute Engine from Google App Engine application. Error message is "You have already reached the maximum number of client IDs for this project". I know, there is the limit - 20 Client IDs for the project. But there is no "Delete" button at this page.
I tried to delete those Client ID at the Permissions page. Group deletion does not work at all. When I delete Client ID one by one item is removed from page visually, but it is still in place after page refresh.
I tried the old version of the api console at 
https://code.google.com/apis/console/
Delete operation is finished with message: "You do not have permission for that operation".

How can I delete extra "Compute Engine and App Engine" Client IDs which my project does not need?

Answer (score 0):

You can login to https://console.developers.google.com/project with your user name and password and select your project(Make sure you have owner permission on that project). Click on "Credentials" and than delete the OAuth keys from that page.

If you still have issues deleting them can you attach the screenshot of the error message.

Comment: This recommendation works good for the Client IDs which you added yourself. "Compute Engine and App Engine" Client Ids I noted above were added automatically and has no option to delete them. So I can not show the error message. We resolved the issue deleting the problematic project and creating the new one where we can proceed with service account. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you provide me some more info on how you were able to create more than 22 Client IDs automatically. I was trying to reproduce it on my end by enabling the Compute API from a non admin user ID but was not able to reproduce it.